# specific text in prompt for pythonscript

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, prompt

In JavaScript, you can use `prompt("This text is above the field of the prompt.", "This text is in the field of the prompt.")` to get a customized window appearing.

In PythonScript you can trigger the prompt by using `input()`, but `input(“Please enter your name”, “Harry Potter”)` doesn't work the way JS does.

**So how can I trigger such behaviour?**

Edit: [Screenshot of what I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNIvx.png)

Here is my simple code, although it isn't necessarily relevant for the question:

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <title>PyScript</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css"/>
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <py-script src="script.py" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**PYTHON**

```
print("Enter the elements for comparison like this: Element1, Element2, Element3")

elements_list = input().split(", ")

def swap(list, i, j):
    temp = list[i]
    list[i] = list[j]
    list[j] = temp
    
for i in range (len(elements_list)-1):
    for i in range (len(elements_list)-1):
        if input (f"""{elements_list[i]} (type 1) or {elements_list[i+1]} (type 2)?""") == "2":
            swap (elements_list, i, i+1)


print("Your order ", elements_list)
```

Comment: Which `input` do you want to have a default value, and what's the default value you want?

Answer (score 0):

To set a default value of `input`, use the `or` operator. If the first value is truthy (evaluates to `True` with `bool(...)`), it returns the left side, otherwise, it returns the right side.

An empty string, `""`, is falsy, so it returns whatever's to the right.

The generic way to do this is:

```py
name = input("What is your name?") or "Alex"
print(f"Your name is {name}")
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't phrase it right, but I want my field to look [like this](https://i.imgur.com/8fdjeeL.png). Specifically, the blue part is important for me.